# Designing a NFA that accept the set of strings that contain an even number of substrings 01

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'm new in theory of computation. Here {0,1} set of input symbols. I tried to make the NFA from L(M)= set of all accepted strings, but unable to complete it. Can someone give some hints that how should I attack this problem? . It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that by *substring* you mean *consecutive substring*.

There is no need to use the power of NFAs. You can construct a DFA which remembers the following information:

- The last symbol seen (either $0$, $1$, or blank).
- The parity of number of occurrences of $01$ seen so far.

Maintaining the last symbol seen is easy. If the last symbol seen is $0$ and the current symbol is $1$, then you flip the parity of number of occurrences of $01$. A state is accepting if the parity of number of occurrences of $01$ seen so far is even.

I'll let you convert this description into an automaton.